# How to fetch data in tabular form in _new page

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a project in ruby on rails. Is it possible to add data just like normal form and save them in database in show page? Is it possible to add data in tabular form and let the user save the data in batch (i.e. 5-6 record at a time) for the same employee? If so, then how can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can read all needed information from file and parse it into the array of objects, and then use https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import gem for insert it in db (for production).

also, you may look into `db/seeds.rb` file for adding new data in develop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....but i want index page to behave as our form,which looks like table,in which we can fill our data and submit it and save it in database.

Comment: Anyway you will edit form one by one. And if you want to make accessible editing on index- edit `index` action, add links for edit 1 element, etc. If you want to use db injection- use said tools in the answer. Maybe you question is not clear enough and you need to clear it out?